# Which Flocculant/Coagulant is ideal for harvesting Algae?

Tags: biochemistry, polymers, proteins

While dealing with Algae fit for human consumption (as protein supplements), which is the most suitable coagulant/Flocculant available?

Factors to consider:

1) Cost Effectiveness (for instance poly glu cost is prohibitive for commercial scale)

2) pH range (If growth medium of algae is alkaline, many coagulants don't work)

3) Suitable for Vegans (Since food grade Algae is often marketed as Vegan food, using Chitosan is not an option)

4) Metallic salts are needed in high doses and are not preferred in general

With these factors in mind, which coagulant/flocculant would be best for harvesting Algae?

Comment: Would it be possible to adjust pH prior to adding coagulant?

Comment: Would be too much of an overhead. We are dealing with 2 Million liters a day, with pH of about 10

Comment: Identical question on [Biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/84046/49363).

Comment: Unless you want to try microalgae EPA based bio-flocculation or autoflocculation of a strain such as Nannochloropsis I would suggest centrifugation, but you'd want to ask that on [Engineering.SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions), you could also ask about seperation using osmosis there. Be certain to mention that you have asked your question on other sites already (and link to your question here).